# Using ViewBag with @Html.CheckBoxFor rather than "plain" <input type= "checkbox">

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, html-helper

Having already used `@Html.CheckBoxFor` within a `View`, I plan to use with the former `Tag Helper` in conjunction to `ViewBag` within the same `View` to circumvent few errors (e.g. variable definition):

**MODEL**

```
   public class test
    {
      public int ItemID { get; set; }
      public string ItemName { get; set; }
      public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
List<test> ItemList = new List<test>();
         ItemList.Add(new test {ItemID=1, ItemName="apple", IsAvailable = false});
         ItemList.Add(new test {ItemID=2, ItemName="mango", IsAvailable = false});
         ItemList.Add(new test {ItemID=3, ItemName="stuck", IsAvailable = false});
         ItemList.Add(new test {ItemID=4, ItemName="blocked", IsAvailable = false});
         ItemList.Add(new test {ItemID=5, ItemName="help:(", IsAvailable = false});
         ViewBag.ItemList = ItemList;
```

**VIEW**

```
<table>
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ItemList)
           {
            <tr><td>
           <input type= "checkbox" id = "Check_@item.ItemID" checked="@item.IsAvailable" 
           onclick="CheckOnlyOneCheckBox(this);"/>
           <label for="Check_@item.ItemID">@item.ItemName</label>
           </tr>
           }
 </table>
```

*2 main issues have been encountered:*

(a) Value of the `selected box` could not retrieved from a `submit button` using

```
   foreach (var item in ViewBag.ItemList)
         {
           if (item.IsCheck)
              {
                var zz = item.ItemName;
               }                     
          }
```

(b) format of the displayed `ItemName` using `<input type= "checkbox">` look slightly different (e.g. bold font) than the ones obtained from a previous `checkbox list` using `@Html.CheckBoxFor`.

Thus any assistance in using `@Html.CheckBoxFor` with `ViewBag` would highly be appreciated.

**EDIT**

@Md Farid Uddin Kiron

The **main issue** lies on the fact that a `checkbox` list has already been defined (in the same same `View`) via:

```
List<test> chk = new List<test>();
          chk.Add(new test() {ReferalTypeId=1, ReferalTypeName = "box1",
IsReferalCheck=false});
          chk.Add(new test() {ReferalTypeId=2, ReferalTypeName = 
"box2", IsReferalCheck=false});
          chk.Add(new test() {ReferalTypeId=3, ReferalTypeName = 
"Other", IsReferalCheck=false});

 CtrList chklist = new CtrList(); // Ctrl being a public class defined 
                                 // in MODEL
 chklist.reflist = chk;  
 return View(chklist);
```

Empirically I've ended up to a situation, where I could not define within `public IActionResult Index()` another `checkbox` list returning something else than `chklist` since the variable (e.g. `list`) won't be defined while looping it from `View`.

As a result I had to use, as a way around: `ViewBag`, enabling me to pass variable from `Model` to `View` without any problem. Without `binding` it, this effective way around has been raising another issue and the solution of last resort I am investigating consists of:

(a) `looping` through the `checkbox`;

(b) identifying the selected value via `ViewBag`;

(c) then finding a way to pass the selected variable from `View` to `Controller`. However, I had to concede that this latter approach looks sub-optimal.

Best

Comment: Why don't you try with `@model List<Test>` instead of `ViewBag.ItemList` any specific reason for `viewBag` here

Comment: @dark.vador Can you share the code from the cshtml?

Comment: So far I have researched on it you can handle `CheckBoxFor` helper with `ViewBag` for single checkbox, but for list of checkboxfor helper bring you into many other problem. First issue is you cannot bind the value with it easily while submit the value to controller. If you want to try instead let me know. There are better solution using `viewModel`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: Thanks indeed for your reply. I've edited the post given the questions while being interesting in knowing best approaches.  Best.

Comment: @Rahatur: Thanks for your feedback. As ```cshtml``` is quite massive, I've edited the post, hoping it helps in accurately understanding the issues encountered. Best

Comment: in order to get values bind to the model, your html inputs has to have a name attribute in them.consider that if you need to have list of checkbox/radio buttons you need to name them equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched a lot on your scenario. The way you planned it cannot execute well because we cannot set `htmlAttributes` on `CheckBoxFor` so in this way we cannot retrive value from the from `CheckBoxFor` as you might know to get value from submitted item we need to set `htmlAttributes` on it like `id` `class` or `name`

So considering your scenario the easiest solution I have founded for you like below:

***Your Predefined Model:***

```
public class CheckBoxTestModel
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }
```

***View Model To Lead Check On View:***

```
 public class CheckBoxFromViewBagModel
    {
        public List<CheckBoxTestModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
        
    }
```

***Controller On Load:***

```
 public IActionResult CheckboxforFromViewBag()
        {
            var checkBoxList = new List<CheckBoxTestModel>()
            {
                new CheckBoxTestModel() { ItemID=1,ItemName="apple", IsAvailable = false },
                new CheckBoxTestModel() { ItemID=2,ItemName="mango", IsAvailable = false },
                new CheckBoxTestModel() { ItemID=3,ItemName="stuck", IsAvailable = false },
                new CheckBoxTestModel() { ItemID=4,ItemName="blocked", IsAvailable = false },
                new CheckBoxTestModel() { ItemID=5,ItemName="help:(", IsAvailable = false },


            };

            var model = new CheckBoxFromViewBagModel();
            model.CheckBoxes = checkBoxList;
            return View(model);
        }
```

***View When Load CheckBox:***

```
@model CheckBoxFromViewBagModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CheckboxforFromViewBag";
}
<h4>Load CheckBox From ViewModel & Submit value to Controller wtih Selected Value</h4>

<hr />
<style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitValueFromCheckBoxList", "UserLog"))
{
    <table class="table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Is Checked</th>

        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxes.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td> @Model.CheckBoxes[i].ItemName</td>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.CheckBoxes[i].IsAvailable)</td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.CheckBoxes[i].ItemID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.CheckBoxes[i].ItemName)

            </tr>

        }
    </table>
    <br />
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Submit To Controller" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

***Controller When Submit The Value:***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SubmitValueFromCheckBoxList(CheckBoxFromViewBagModel checkBoxViewModel)
        {
            var checkBoxValueFromView = checkBoxViewModel;
            return Ok(checkBoxValueFromView);
        }
```

***Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** As per your scenario I think this would the eligant way to handle this. Other than either of the work around bring us another
> chanllenge. In my solution you can ignore the `CSS` part. Here the important and tricky part is `@Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.CheckBoxes[i].ItemID) @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.CheckBoxes[i].ItemName)` sets `htmlAttributes` for us.

I hope it would help you well.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for the time devoted to this post. Furthermore, the explanations are very clear. Much appreciated, hence my gratefulness. Best regards.

Comment: Glad to investigate your problem.